# Basic Javascript/math in QML... why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript, math, qml

I'm pretty new to QML. According to the QML documentation at http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativescope.html, the Text object should show 15, but instead it only outputs 5. Can anyone help me out?

```
Text {
    id: counter
    x: 300;
    y: 300;
    property int a: 5;
    function randNumber(a){
        var a = a+10;
        return a;
    }
    text: a;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a` in your function is local to the function because you prefaced it with `var`. Instead, make it:

```
    function randNumber(a){
        a = a+10;
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I still can't get it to output 15:
    Text {
        id: counter;
        x: 300;
        y: 300;
        property int a: 5;
        function randNumber(a){
            a = a+10;
            return a;
        }
        text: a;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You're never actually calling your `randNumber` function, so it will have no effect. If you want to set `text` to the result of `randNumber(a)`, you should be doing `text: randNumber(a)`. Or without defining a function:

```
text : {
    var a = a+10;
    return a;
}
```

If you remove the `var`, the `a` property will also be set to 15 (with the above code only `text` would be set to 15 and `a` would remain 5).

Answer (score 0):

Neither pass it as an argument to the function nor create a new variable in the `randNumber` function using `var`. Simply use `a`. It should be availble in the function, since the function in inside the `Text` QML Component.

This is not working since you are not calling the function anywhere in your program. I assume that you want to call it on the start-up(technically when the Text component is loaded). So you can call it on the `Component.onCompleted` function.

```
Text {
    id: counter
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    property int a: 5;
    function randNumber(){
        a = a+10;
        return a;
    }
    text: a;
    Component.onCompleted: randNumber();
}
```

Look into this [documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/5.0/qtquick-usecase-integratingjs.html#adding-javascript-functions-in-qml) for more examples.